# how to make height auto depends in screen resolution

Tags: css, html, scroll, height

I've been thinking this for almost a days. But I can't find any solution in my problem.

Is there a way to set auto height **div with scroll bar**, because as of now I'm using a fix height but I see the problem that when I open it in another laptop or pc with bigger or smaller screen resolution its still in the fix height.

Here's my div:

```
<div style="overflow:auto; width:1050px; height:760px;">
```

[here's my link so you can see the program](http://www.mediafire.com/?9cskdbpflgvetha)

All I want is the height will be auto depending in the screen resolution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a script to get the computed window height and set it equal to the targeted element height. In this instance, the function is executed on load and on resize. Each element with a class of `autoheight` will be given a height equal to the height of the window's height:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GN7eK/)**

```
var setElementHeight = function () {
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.autoheight').css('min-height', (height));
};

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    setElementHeight();
}).resize();
```

The above method is fine as it doesn't require any changes other than the addition of a class; however if you wanted to avoid using jQuery, you could do something like this instead:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BXFwp/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.autoheight {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: @JoshC...uhm..can you help me also on how I can apply it in my program... I just copy paste it but i dont know what to do to make it run because i dont have background in using javascript. :(

Comment: @JoshC...I was thinking why there is scroll bar if the browser height is calculated. It should be no scroll bar...

Comment: That's because I added blank space under it to show that it is working. The background:blue is representative of the screen size, and thus the top content.

Comment: @JochC...I seee....if it is computing the height of the browser so it will also computing the screen resolution..So, i think that one i was looking for...uhm...can you help me to apply it?? because i just paste it inside of script...:( sorry for being newbei in javascript

Comment: You also need JQuery for it to work. Try the latest version. Then place the class ' autoheight ' on whatever you want this done to.

Comment: @JoshC....is this correct...I paste your code inside of this function autoHeight(){ } then <div class = "autoHeight">??? but its not working... really really sorry...

Comment: Look at my updated demo. It's a jsFiddle, you can see all the coding.

Comment: @JoshC..Thanks... I think the main problem now is in my design..all of the content is all blue and there is no scroll..hmmm thank you for helping me

Comment: @JoshC...I still have more questions but I'm worrying that it may annoying to you...If ever I can't solved my problem can I have your email? if its okay to you

Answer (score 0):

You can try using fixed position:

```
<div style="position:fixed; overflow:auto; width:100%; height:100%;">
```

Comment: @YotamOmer...I already tried that before but its not fitted in my screen...nor not working

Comment: @PrincessToledo can you send me a link to your website or some more code so I can take a closer look?

Comment: @YotamOmer...I edit my post and there's a link so you can download my program...its only one file..thanks for heelp :)

Answer (score 0):

do you want to use css for height ?

```css
.autoHeight {
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center; background: #3292d3;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 24px;
margin: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<h2> autoHeight for css </h2>
<div class='autoHeight'> <p> you can resize screen to see exact height works or not. </p> </div>
```

if you want to get height using jQuery

```js
var setElementHeight = function () {
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.autoheight').css('min-height', (height));
};

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    setElementHeight();
}).resize();
```

```css
.autoheight {
    background-color: #3292d3;
    font-size:24px;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="autoheight">
    <h1>try resizing the window vertically. and see the result</h1>
</div>
```